# Google Place API used application working only android 2.3 not in the above versions

Tags: android, google-places-api, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I developed an android application that uses Google Place API. The application is working fine in Android 2.3 and not working in android 4.1.

try {

```
        HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
        Log.d("cp", "1");
        HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_SEARCH_URL));
        Log.d("cp", "2");
        request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
        Log.d("cp", "3");
        request.getUrl().put("location", _latitude + "," + _longitude);
        Log.d("cp", "4");
        request.getUrl().put("radius", _radius); // in meters
        Log.d("cp", "5");
        request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");
        Log.d("cp", "6");
        if (types != null)
            request.getUrl().put("types", types);
        Log.d("cp", "7");

        PlacesList list = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);
        Log.d("cp", "8");
        // Check log cat for places response status
        Log.d("Places Status", "" + list.status);
        return list;

    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        Log.e("Error:", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
```

the log is showing till Log.d("cp", "7"); and not showing Log.d("cp", "8"); and Log.d("Places Status", "" + list.status);
not also the error log Log.e("Error:", e.getMessage());

Comment: What's your error while running in `android 4.1`

Comment: And  also Post those codes where it's showing you error.

Comment: the code and log from Samsung Grand duos is included in the edits